# .htaccess RewriteRule , redirect to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect url to a specific format. For example

abcd.com             ->  https://www.abcd.com

www.abcd.com         ->  https://www.abcd.com

http://www.abcd.com  ->  https://www.abcd.com

loalhost/def         ->  https://localhost/def

192.168.x.10/def     ->  https://192.168.x.10/def

How to write a simple RewriteCond and rule to cover all the above rules ?

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these redirect rules in the site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for abcd.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(abcd\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# for rest
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```